# Error: 'Node' is undefined. javascript error

Tags: angularjs

I have written the following code in the HTML file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Project Tracking Home Page</title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome To Project Tracker</h1>
        <p>Addition of Two Numbers (100+100) is - {{100+100}}</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The binding expressions do not return the value instead they are shown as it is.
When i run this code, i find the error ''Node' is undefined.'

I have used NuGet packages to install the Angular Js and JQuery into the scripts folder.

Comment: I think you may need to read up a little more on getting an application running with angularjs

Comment: Delete all the other tags in the header except the title and angular script.. Can you see the value 200 ?? if not, it means that there is something wrong with the downloaded angular script from NuGet

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your browser's document mode is greater than IE 8

Comment: what if he wants to run it in IE8

Comment: I use IE9 and `Node is undefined` error still persists. i have also added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` tag in my code. What could be done to solve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

If it's IE, try this:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

Comment: I have added the above tag in my code and the `Node is undefined` error still persists. I use IE9. Please suggest a way to fix the bug?

Comment: This worked for me, but really shouldn't have. I'd previously developed and deployed an mvc app with angular that ran fine. I added a new view/controller and began seeing this Node is undefined error. Adding the meta tag cleared the error, which makes no sense.